# Why recyclerView's viewholder is null in Android when the views are hidden?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I know it's a little bit generic. So I have a recyclerView, and inside it there are multiple items which can expand and collapse (each of them has a webview and expand and collapse to decide if the full content needs to be shown). I need to set images for a BiImageView in the viewAdapter like this

```
ItemViewHolder viewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) recyclerView
                .findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(position);
viewHolder.rightIndicator.setImageResources()
```

However it only works when every item is collapsed, when the first item expand, it will take up the screen and other items will be hidden or say below the bottom of the screen. Then only the first few items can set the image resource. For other hidden items, the `viewHolder` is null. It looks like recyclerView removed them from layout, I'm wondering if there is any way to make sure I can get the viewHolder? Like some callback? I tried `onCreate` and `onBind`, but when I scroll down or collapse the first item, these two methods didn't get called.

Comment: onBindViewHolder is called everytime the cell is visible. So when you scroll down to see the hidden items, the adapter will draw the changes

Comment: The problem now is that, it looks like `onBindViewHolder ` did happened, when I collapse the first item and scroll down, I couldn't see `onBindViewHolder ` gets called again. I mentioned it inside the question but used `onBind` for short.

Comment: It depends on your Adapter realization. Do you use different item view types in your adapter to collapse/expand your views and removing/inserting items?

Comment: @H.Taras it is the same view type, there are xmls for expand and collapse which was done by binding a boolean inside the viewModel

Answer (score 0):

I think, I can help you with some pseudo code, but I dont remember how to use it with view model. First of all, you have to change all your views in `onBindViewHolder` method in depend on your model, then in your model class you must have field, for example

```
boolean expanded = false; // initial state
```

And in your onBindViewHolder:

```
if (modelsList.get(position).isExpanded()){
//show expanded view
} else {
//show collapsed view
}
```

After it, you can set onClickListener to some view in your collapsed view, to expand:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
modelsList.get(position).setIsExpanded(!modelsList.get(position).getIsExpanded());
MyAdapter.this.notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

When you will click on this view, your model will change and RecyclerView will recreate view binded to this model with new data.
Hope it will help you